# How to capture value from query and use it as a value in another query

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-redshift, airflow, mysql-python

I have a Postgres(redshift) query that I am running in Python that outputs a field and its value. I want to run another query that uses that value from that query. However when I run the below code, it is giving me an error:

```
taskinstance.py:1051} ERROR - no results to fetch
```

Here is my code:

```
def get_etl_recordd():
    pg_hook = PostgresHook(postgre_conn_id="postgres_default", schema='db1')
    connection = pg_hook.get_conn()
    nt_cur = connection.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.NamedTupleCursor)
    atest_update_query = "select max(updated_at) from schema1.table1 group by updated_at order by updated_at asc limit 1;"
    nt_cur.execute(atest_update_query)
    result = nt_cur.fetchone()
    max_updated_at = result.max

    cursor2= connection.cursor()
    latest_update_query1 = "select * from schema1.table1 where updated_at <= '{}'; commit;".format(max_updated_at)
    cursor2.execute(latest_update_query1)

    d=cursor2.fetchone()
    connection.close()
```

Any idea as to why this is occurring? The value from `atest_updated_query` is a timestamp and `latest_updated_query1` does in fact have an output. Any help would be appreciated.

This is a Postgres(Redshift) query that I am running in Python/Airflow.

Comment: please clean up the typos (e.g., `atest_updated_query, `latest_upadted_query1`, `get_etl_recordd()`)

Answer (score 1):

I cannot spot a problem in your code, but what you could try using a `get_first` method of the `PostgresHook`. It's supposed to do exactly what you're trying to achieve, and it for sure works in our airflow/redshift setup.

```
sql = "SELECT 1"

hook = PostgresHook(postgres_conn_id=self.postgres_conn_id, schema=self.database)

first_col_of_first_row = self.hook.get_first(sql)[0]
```

Comment: So, lines 2 and 3 should be defined within a custom operator? How did you implement this? Or do you just run it within a Python Operator task?

Comment: If it's just a one of think, then I would not bother wrapping it in an operator. But if you use it more often, do create one.